# Changing php version in mamp

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I am using the latest version of MAMP.
In my MAMP settings, I can find the latest version of PHP as 7.1.1,
but when I run `php -v` i get this:

```
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I am not able to change it.
There is no folder like `php5.5.14` inside `MAMP/bin/php/`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's because it's referring to the pre-installed PHP of your *OSX*. You need to change that to point to your MAMP PHP. To do so you need to edit the `.bash_profile` with a text editor and add the MAMP version of PHP to the `PATH` variable.

Follow these steps ([source](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)):

> 1. Within the Terminal, run

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

> 2. Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin:$PATH
```

> 3. Hit ESC, Type `:wq`, and hit *Enter*
> 4. In Terminal, run:

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

> 5. In Terminal, type in which php again and look for the updated string.
>      If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP
>      PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal
window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes.

Comment: Solve my problem for my needing to using php7 without re-install MAMP